# Access TrueCrypt mount over network

Tags: linux, vmware, network-shares, truecrypt

I'm running Linux Mint in a Virtual Machine (VMWare) with a Windows 7 as host. I shared one of my Windows partitions to access it in the Linux guest using Samba because of a problem with permissions I had using VMWare's Shared Folders.

Anyway... In Windows I used some time ago a TrueCrypt volume file, just for fun, and it always worked fine. But I was very curious if I could mount the same file in the Linux environment.

I've downloaded the "installer" and mounted successfully the volume, using the GUI and through the Terminal, and I could access the file smoothlessly.

I could stop, but noooooo.... I wanted to access this mounted volume, the files encrypted on it, over the network, virtually from anywhere: The Windows Host, a smartphone, another computer in the workgroup...

But when opening the target directory, instead of see the files and folders like in the OS where the volume was mounted, the folder is empty.

I think this is the normal behavior but it was nice to confirm and know if it's possible to workaround.

Comment: .... Your smartphone does not have the ability to decrypt a Truecrypt volume.  Linux and Windows does not have that same problem.  Questions about Android devices are specifically not on topic here at Superuser.

Comment: Just because I mentioned an Android app this means I'm asking something related to Android? Of course not.

Comment: Your trying to access a TrueCrypt on an Android device, correct?  If you are not doing then don't even mention the Android device.

Comment: No, I'm trying to access the **result** of a TrueCrypt device in a Android device. I could say I have another computer and I was trying to access that folder over the network. I was just being specific. But if you don't like it, then change the Android scenario to Windows. The target folder of mounted volume can be accessed in the Windows host, but it's also empty.

Comment: Clarify the problem the inclusion of android is confusing since android has zero support for TrueCrypt

Comment: Sigh... Better?

Answer (score 0):

My understanding of your question is different to @Ramhound - Can you confirm you are trying to access the contents of the truecrypt volume, rather then the volume container ?  If so, I don't see that as normal behaviour for Linux.

I posit that it may be a permission problem, ie the Truecrypt volume may be mounted as 1 user, SAMBA access is via another user, and the read/write permissions are not set to allow this - and this should be solvable by changing the way its mounted (eg passing the appropriate options via --fs-options) and/or the SAMBA permissions.

Comment: Yes, I mounted the volume successfully in a directory accessible by the smartphone but I could access it only in the Linux environment.